# Does Eclipse allow add custome button/command?

Tags: eclipse, button, shortcut

I have project group in Eclipse.
But I use debug as --> on server 99% of time.
It takes next operations: select project in Navigator, right click, select Debug As, select debug on server, left click.

Is it possible to put on toolbar 1 button that will do all above (5 actions) with 1 mouse click on it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just done that, doesn't pressing the "Debug" button (with the bug on it) do exactly that (i.e. repeat the last action)?

Of course, if you want to generalise this, I'm afraid you'll have to write a plugin that contributes such a button...And that's probably more trouble than it's worth. Maybe Eclipse 4 will make this easier through better scripting capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I have ran my apps on my phone is by going to Run and then to run or debug configurations, go to the application manager and click the add page button. After that you can easily just go select your project and then in taget tab you can decide on what to do. After that you can just click "run" and it works like a charm.